# syntax error in C

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to build  a block where I am getting this error message

`pprbc_CONTENT_icverification_act.c", line 99.2: 1506-018 (S) Operand of indirection operator must be a pointer expression`

Can anyone please explain what this means?

code below:

```
   *(WORK_migration_ind_f) =
   *(migration_status_in_MI9_CIRCLE_INFO(WORK_source_circle_f));
```

Comment: Any chance you could show the code upon which the error message is being generated? Because, by itself, the error message indicates that maybe you're trying to dereference a literal object or primitive type - when really you can only deference a pointer. i.e. you can't declare `int myval` then try `myval->something` because myval is not a pointer..

Comment: Actually it's probably a structure. I bet you declared `struct mystruct { int something; }` and then tried `struct mystruct myobj` followed by a `myobj->something` when you meant `myobj.something`, right?

Comment: Thanks for updating your post with the code causing the error. Now, can you guess what we want to know now? Can you? Can you? Aww.. you're disappointing me, surely it is obvious what the next question is??? Yes.. we want to know the TYPES of `WORK_source_circle_f` and `WORK_migration_ind_f`.. don't you want to know that too? Aren't you the least bit curious why your compiler thinks you're not using a pointer? I'm curious and I want you to be curious too! Get hungry! Hunger for that knowledge! Programming is fun when you're hungry for the truth :)

Comment: And let us know what the prototype of `migration_status_in_MI9_CIRCLE_INFO` is - perhaps it is not returning a pointer.. if you are having difficulty finding the definition it is worth having a look at the `grep` tool.

Comment: .. any lawyers present should cite me for badgering the witness..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you put a '*' in front of something that isn't a pointer.

You'd be doing yourself and everybody a favor if you posted the line of code involved.

Comment: solved it. the function `migration_status_in_MI9_CIRCLE_INFO(WORK_source_circle_f)`returns a char pointer. but that header file should be included some where deep below in the core of the application which was missing. so since the header was not included compiler was assuming  that the function will return an inetger resulting the error above. thanks a lot for all your advices:)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have code something like this:

```
int x;

*x;    // apply indirection to non-poiner
```

But it's impossible to say without seeing the actual code that causes the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` (indirection) operator dereferences a pointer; that is, it converts a pointer value to an l-value. The operand of the indirection operator must be a pointer to a type.

Answer (score 1):

Either the variable `WORK_migration_ind_f` or the return type of the function `migration_status_in_MI9_CIRCLE_INFO` (or both) is not a pointer type.  You can dereference only a pointer.

If you have code like:

```
int *pi;
int i;
int f(void);
int *pf(void);
```

Then, the following "makes sense":

```
*pi /* is of type int */
*pf() /* is of type int */
```

The following doesn't:

```
*i /* can't dereference a non-pointer */
*f() /* can't dereference a non-pointer */
```

If you show us the declarations of `WORK_migration_ind_f` and `WORK_migration_ind_f`, we can tell you more, but I think you should be able to figure the error out on your own now.